# how to use Formik to send data with multiple subforms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am building a react app with DRF, and I am trying to build some flashcards, inspired by the app Quizlet. Whenever you create a deck in Quizlet you get a form: in this you need to create a deck instance and multiple card instances which means that you need to send post requests to 2 different endpoints (I am using postgres: there are two tables

```
Deck: title, description, directory_id, ...
Card: side1, side2, deck_id, ...
```

)

My question is, how would I go about this using formik in react? Do I use multiple Formik components like this

```
import { Formik, Form } from "formik"
cardForms = () => {
  for (i to n)
     <Formik ...>
}
...
return (
  { */ formik component for deck title and description */ }
  <Formik ... />
  
  {*/ formik component for each card form */}
  {cardForms}
)
```

It seems that it could work, however there are multiple problems with my solution. Each formik component would have a onSubmit prop. This means that I would hit the database n times (one for each card, plus the hit to create the actual deck). This is incredibly inefficient. I would like to have just two `Formik` components: one for the deck and one for all the cards. But how would I go about it? Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just 1 Formik context for this. Just use formik's `FieldArray` component to access the individual cards. For example
assuming your initial data is something like this:

```
{
  title: "deck title",
  description: "deck description",
  cards: [{
     side1: "side 1",
     side2: "side 2"
  }]
}
```

```
<Formik>
  {({ values }) => (
  <Form>
   <Field name="title"/>
   <Field name="description"/>
   <FieldArray name="cards">
     {({ insert, remove, push }) => (
        <div>
        {
           values.cards.map((card,index) => {
               return <Field name={`cards.${index}.sid1`}></Field>
           })
        }
        </div>
     )})
     
   </FieldArray>
  </Form>
 )}
<Formik>
```

More info here : https://formik.org/docs/examples/field-arrays

Comment: thank you very much I did not check the FieldArray component